# JavaScript/JQuery: Problem with Object Properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm calling the $.ajax function using JQuery. The php that is called returns a string structured as such "varname=varvalue&varname2=varvalue2". I'm breaking it all up and creating an object that uses the varnames as properites and the varvalues as values of those properties. Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
           type:"POST",
           url:"/actions/savebbuilderdata.php",
           data:({step: stepNum, submitObj: saveObj}),
           complete:function(jqXHR, textStatus){
               var returnObj = new Object();
               var returnArr = jqXHR.responseText.split("&");
               for(i=0;i<returnArr.length;i++){
                   var tempArr = returnArr[i].split("=");
                   returnObj[tempArr[0]] = tempArr[1];
               }
               //For Testing that the values are infact being assigned
               for(prop in returnObj){
                   alert(prop + ": " + returnObj[prop]);
               }
                alert(returnObj.returnText);
           }
           });
```

Notice the second for loop. I'm simply doing that to get an alert for each property within the object. This works correctly and shows each property name with the correct value. One of the properties being returned is always 'returnText'. However, when I call the final alert attempting to get that returnText I get 'undefined'. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: I suggest you use Firebug (Firefox extension) and instead of the second for loop write: `console.dir(returnObj);`

Comment: Does the `returnText` property get alerted correctly in the loop before you try to alert it on its own?

Comment: I second the Firebug recommendation. You'll want to either use Firebug or Webkit's console tools to examine your Object in greater detail. It's entirely possible that you have a property whose data is undefined or something else going on, and you'll need a debugger to see that.

Comment: I do use Firebug. Don't know why I didn't think to use the console. It should that the returnText property was coming back with some carriage returns, which is weird since there aren't any in the php string. Not a big deal. Used replace to remove them, and it works just fine now. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you return the data as a json encoded array instead? Much easier to work with

Answer (score 0):

I can't see much wrong with the code, but maybe these can help you identify the problem.  I would use `success` instead of `complete` to make sure the problem isn't in the transfer of information.

I also extract the `deparameterize` code into a separate function because it is both easier to test and seems like something I would do again.

```
String.prototype.deparameterize = function() {
    var hsh = new Object;

    var pairs = this.split("&");

    for(i=0;i<pairs.length;i++){
       var pair = pairs[i].split("="); 
       hsh[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    }

    return hsh;
}

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/actions/savebbuilderdata.php",
    data:({step: stepNum, submitObj: saveObj}),
    success:function(data, textStatus,jqXHR){
        var obj = data.deparameterize();
        alert(obj.returnText);
    }
});
```

Note: not always best practice to extend String, but maybe in this case it works.

Comment: Check my reply to the comments in my post. It was actually an issue with carriage returns coming back in my php. I just had to add a replace statement to make sure they got removed.